# Convert 2bpp greyscale image to compressed byte array

Tags: c#, image, encoding, binary, byte

can someone tell me whats wrong when converting a 2bpp greyscale image to compressed byte array?
the compressed format would be W * H * Color.

currently I am taking this image..
[image]

running it through this..

```
  public byte[] ToBytes(ImageData imageData)
  {
      byte imageDepth  = 4;
      int  imageWMin   = imageData.GetWidth();
      int  imageHMin   = imageData.GetHeight();
      int  imageWMax   = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)imageData.GetWidth()  / 16) * 16;
      int  imageHMax   = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)imageData.GetHeight() / 16) * 16;
      int  byteCount   = ((imageWMax + imageHMax * imageWMax) * imageDepth) / 256;
      byte[] data = new byte[byteCount];

      //Loop though tiles
      for (int ty = 0; ty < imageHMax/8; ty++)
      for (int tx = 0; tx < imageWMax/8; tx++)
      {
          //Loop through pixels
          for (int py = 0; py < 8; py++)
          for (int px = 0; px < 8; px++)
          {      
              int pixelX     = tx + px;
              int pixelY     = ty + py;
              int pixelColor = 0;
              int pixelByte  = ((pixelX + pixelY * imageWMax) * imageDepth) / 256;

              if (pixelX < imageWMin && pixelY < imageHMin)
                  pixelColor = Math.Min((imageData.GetPixel(pixelX, pixelY).intValue0 / 64), 3);

              Console.WriteLine("{ " + pixelX.ToString() + ", " + pixelY.ToString() + " } = " + pixelColor.ToString() + " at byte: " + pixelByte.ToString());
              data[pixelByte] = (byte)((data[pixelByte] & ~(byte)0x4) | ((byte)pixelColor & (byte)0x4));
          }
      }
      return data;
  }

    public override void Load() //runs on boot
    {
        imageData = Image.NewImageData("test.png");
        image     = Graphics.NewImage(imageData);
        image.SetFilter(FilterMode.Nearest, FilterMode.Nearest, 1);
        bytes     = ToBytes(imageData);

        Console.WriteLine("saving to " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt")) Console.WriteLine("file: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt does not exist!");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"test.txt", bytes);
    }

    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        Boot.Run(new Test2BPP());
    }
```

and getting the decoded binary output as this..

`04 04 00 00`

which I am guessing it should be 2 bytes instead of 4 because 16*8*4 = 512 or a integer value of 2 bytes

so just to be clear i want to save each 8x8 part of the image top left to bottom right as a byte or 2 bits per pixel (TILEWIDTH * TILEHEIGHT * COLORSPERPIXEL).

if the image is less then a power of 8 on the x or y axis then it defaults the remaining values as 0.

Comment: When you say "converting a 2bpp greyscale image to compressed byte array", you mean you expect each pixel to take up two bits, and therefore each byte in your output should contain 4 pixels, yes?  So "packed" rather than "compressed"?

Comment: sorry yes, each pixel holds a value from 0-3 ceilinged to a 8x8 tile grid. so if the image was 12x8 it would fill empty zero's until it was 16x8

Comment: Hmm, something still doesn't make sense.  Your source image is 16x8 pixels, with the Ceiling applied to `imageHMax` it's effectively 16x16 pixels which is 256 pixels.  Even packing them at 4 pixels per byte, that's still 64 bytes in the expected output as I see it, not the 4 you have posted.  Are you sure `byteCount` is correct?  If `imageDepth` is in bits, to convert to bytes you should divide by 8, not 256.

Comment: oh I didn't realize i was ceiling it by a 16x16 grid it was supposed to be a 8x8 grid. also imageDepth is the number of colors per pixel not the bits per pixel.

Comment: Even if the grid is 8x8, you still have a source image of 16x8 pixels = 128 pixels, at 2 bits per pixel, that's 256 bits of data in your source.  The output you have posted is only 32 bits of data (4 bytes at 8 bits per byte), and you haven't explained what your method is for squeezing 256 bits of data into 32 bits.  If your intention is to create a packed, byte array of the raw bitmap data, then your code isn't far off that, except that it contains several errors.  Could you edit your question to explain what you're trying to achieve a little more?

Comment: I edited the question a bit more to explain what i want to do. hopefully its more clear.

Comment: @Travor oh i think i see what your saying. I think your math is wrong 2 bits can store a value of 4 while the rest of the bits are used for the pixel position of the current tile. idk though i'm not quite sure if my math is correct either.

Comment: I checked that PNG's header chunk, and it's RGB ([color type 2](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html)), not 2bpp greyscale.